# WebSocket connection with nodejs express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, websocket

I'm trying to connect to websocket with express but it doesn't connect. I'm trying to send a message to HTML page with WebSocket.

**My Server Side**

```
  var expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);


  app.ws('/echo', function (ws, req) {
      ws.on('message', function (msg) {
        ws.send(msg);
      });
   });
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      var form;
      var websocket;
      function init() {
         form = document.getElementById("isyeribul");
         websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/");
         websocket.onopen = function(evt) {
             console.log("CONNECTED");
         };
         websocket.onmessage = function(event) {
             form.style.display = "none";

         };
      }
        window.addEventListener("load", init, false);

      function sendfunc(){
        var text=document.getElementById("txt1").value;
        websocket.send(text);
        console.log(text+ "  sent");
      }



    </script>
```

**Console output**

```
isyeriara:30 WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
```

Comment: help article : https://www.pubnub.com/blog/nodejs-websocket-programming-examples/

Answer (score 0):

From this docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/readyState

`websocket.readyState` has 4 states:

- 0 CONNECTING  Socket has been created. The connection is not yet open.
- 1 OPEN    The connection is open and ready to communicate.
- 2 CLOSING The connection is in the process of closing.
- 3 CLOSED  The connection is closed or couldn't be opened.

From this doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

> As establishing a connection is asynchronous and prone to failure there is no guarantee that calling the send() method immediately after creating a WebSocket object will be successful. We can at least be sure that attempting to send data only takes place once a connection is established by defining an onopen event handler to do the work

Here is a minimal working example:

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
require('express-ws')(app);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './public/index.html'));
});

app.ws('/echo', function(ws, req) {
  ws.on('message', function(msg) {
    ws.send(msg);
  });
});

const port = 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.info(`HTTP server is listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

`./public/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <form id="isyeribul"><input id="txt1" value="websocket example" type="search" placeholder="search" /></form>
    </main>
    <script>
      var form;
      var websocket;
      function init() {
        form = document.getElementById('isyeribul');
        websocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/echo');
        websocket.onopen = function(evt) {
          console.log('CONNECTED');
          sendfunc();
        };
        websocket.onmessage = function(event) {
          form.style.display = 'none';
        };
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

      function sendfunc() {
        var text = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
        websocket.send(text);
        console.log(text + '  sent');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result from `console` of browser:

```
websocket example  sent
```